# Как реализовать задержку между выполнением методов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем, есть доска и бананы. При нажатии на доску, есть шанс, что начнется "шторм". Тут в течении 15-20 секунд должны появляться бананы (примерно по 10-15 в сек). Сообствено, как это реализовать? Я пытался сделать это с помощью цикла for и метода Invoke(), но получилась такая *****, что мой компьютер перезагрузился. Вот мой крутой код :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
Invoke("SpawnBanana", 0.1f);
```

}

Сам метод SpawnBanana() работает нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в том, что вы вызвали `Invoke` 150 раз в одно и то же время, а значит, через 0.1 секунды у вас функция вызовется сразу 150 раз.

Ваша задача сводится к тому, чтобы делать действия через определенный временной интервал.
В юнити такое обычно делается через корутину:

```
private IEnumerator SpawnBananas (int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        SpawnBanana ();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f); // задержка между бананами
    }
}
```

Вызываем:

```
var coroutine = StartCoroutine (SpawnBananas (150));
```

Если нужно прервать спавн бананов раньше времени:

```
StopCoroutine (coroutine);
```